# Tea strainer clogged

Tags: equipment

Has anyone tried this method to remove tannin build up from a clogged fine mesh METAL tea strainer?
A method that I have found to work, is to "BURN" it off with a blow torch or other EXTREME heat source until the mesh begins to get red, and then it just brushes off with a brass suede brush or similar as a fine dust.
(btw Don't try this at home folks! tea hee ;)
Only joking, cos this really works and in a few moments when nothing else that I have tried does.
Not a suitable method for plastic framed strainers.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. This isn't a question, and so doesn't fit into our Q&A format. You could ask and answer the question yourself if you like; check our [tour](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/tour) for more information.

Comment: I can't see a question here. "Has anyone tried this? Don't try this! Just kidding, it's great!" What?

Answer (score 2):

OK, this may seem strange to a lot of other people, but being British, tea is of the utmost importance to us, thus deserves an answer!  Firstly, what is the water like where you are?  This may not be tannin, but a build up of deposits in the water.  Try using a water softener, or a Brita filter, then make your tea in the usual manner.